# Soap Php Example

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I try to use some SOAP.
Here is what I have with SoapUI.

I Have to give Username,Password. But I dont know when I should put it.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:mob="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Mobilog.Serveur.API.DTO.ParamRetour" xmlns:mob1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Mobilog.Serveur.API.DTO.ParamRetour.Dossiers3CE" xmlns:mob2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Mobilog.Serveur.API.DTO.Dossiers3CE">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:SaveDossier3CE>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:paramSaveDossier3CE>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mob:Authentification>?</mob:Authentification>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mob:Origine>?</mob:Origine>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mob:Password>?</mob:Password>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mob:Username>?</mob:Username>
            <mob:CodeUsr>?</mob:CodeUsr>
            <!--Optional:-->



<?php

 $soap = new SoapClient("file.wsdl");
$soap->SaveDossier3CE();


?>
```

Where Should I put the "Password / Origine" var ? I tried something like this :

```
<?php


$soap->SaveDossier3CE(array('username'=>'blabla'));


?>
```

Didnt work.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Usually they are sent as parameters to the function call.

```
$soap->SaveDossier3CE($username,$password);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to have access to the WSDL, I would advise you to try to generate the corresponding PHP classes that will show you how to easily send this sort of request.

I strongly advise you to use a WSDL to PHP generator such as [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator)